# iOS Home Screen Interface - Under the Hood

Tags: ios, safari, homescreen

I am reaching out to the community for insights into the iOS Add to Home Screen capability, due to some specific observed limitations.

Scenario:

Web application with SSL digital certificate.  iPhone 4 and 5 have the same behavior described as follows:

Launch the application from Safari, application loads reliably, via Wifi, 3G and 4G.

The problem (inconsistent load of application) occurs after you "Add to Home Screen" in order to run the web app in the "full screen" mode.  At least half of the time, a "blank screen" appears and the network activity stops.  At from this point, nothing else occurs.  But as soon as I go back to Safari to load the app, it loads fine.

This behavior occurs across multiple devices.  It's as if the Home Screen Icon app is a limited subset of Safari, and lacks "robustness" in certain circumstances.

Does anyone know much about exactly what this capability is, and what its limitations are, and where on the Apple support site this capability is documented and supported?  Anyone else having this kind of issue?

Thanks .....